# Check if value exists in JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I check in my array of objects, if a specific item exists (in my case MachineId with id 2)?

```
[{"MachineID":"1","SiteID":"20"},{"MachineID":"2","SiteID":"20"},{"MachineID":"3","SiteID":"20"},{"MachineID":"4","SiteID":"20"}]
```

I tried this:

```
if (index instanceof machineIds.MachineID) {
    alert('value is Array!');
} else {
    alert('Not an array');
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In cross browser way you may use [`jQuery.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) method for it:

```
var item = $.grep(machineIds, function(item) {
    return item.MachineID == index;
});

if (item.length) {
    alert("value is Array!");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The simplest to understand solution is to loop over the array, and check each one.

```
var match;
for (var i = 0; i < yourArray.length; i++) {
   if (yourArray[i].MachineId == 2) 
        match = yourArray[i];
}
```

Note if there is more than one matching item, this will return the last one.  You can also dress this up in a function.

```
function findByMachineId(ary, value) {
   var match;
    for (var i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
       if (ary[i].MachineId == value) 
            match = ary[i];
    }
    return match;
}
```

Comment: For the specified data, you should compare to `"2"` instead of `2`.

Comment: Or just remove one of those `=` signs

Answer (score 4):

There are many **standard** solution, you don't need third party libraries or loop iteratively.

- [Array `some` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) - since JavaScript 1.6.
- [Array `find` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) - since ES6
- [Array `findIndex` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) - since ES6

For example, using `some()`;

```
var yourArray = [{"MachineID":"1","SiteID":"20"},{"MachineID":"2","SiteID":"20"},{"MachineID":"3","SiteID":"20"},{"MachineID":"4","SiteID":"20"}];

var params = {searchedID: "2", elementFound: null};
var isCorrectMachineID = function(element) {
    if (element.MachineID == this.searchedID);
        return (this.elementFound = element);
    return false;
};

var isFound = yourArray.some(isCorrectMachineID, params)
```

Array `some` method  accepts two parameters:

- callback - Function to test for each element.
- thisObject - Object to use as this when executing callback.

Callback function is not coupled with the iteration code and, using thisObject parameter, you can even return to the caller the element found or more data.
If such an element is found, `some` **immediately** returns true

http://jsfiddle.net/gu8Wq/1/

Comment: Tried in Chrome 46. Could not see it in prototype. Is this function really available with all browsers?

Comment: Please have a look here: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.17 and here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 2):

You could use this condition:

```
if (arr.filter(function(v){return this.MachineID == 2;}).length > 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Old question at this point, but here's an ES6 solution that uses [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
let machine2 = machines.find((machine) => machine.id === '2');
if (machine2) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this does NOT work in all of IE and in half of mobile browsers (as of november 2016): [MDN  Array.find browser compability](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Sure. If you're using ES6, you should be using Babel (or some comparable transpiler.)

Answer (score 0):

```
var item = [{"MachineID":"1","SiteID":"20"},{"MachineID":"2","SiteID":"20"},{"MachineID":"3","SiteID":"20"},{"MachineID":"4","SiteID":"20"}];

var newItem = item.filter(function(i) {
  return i.MachineID == 2;  //it will return an object where MachineID matches with 2
});

console.log(newItem);  // will print [{"MachineID":"2","SiteID":"20"}]
```

Comment: please describe working of your code or use self explanatory comments!